# Share nlog config with multiple projects and the proper threadsafe way to all write to the same log file?

Tags: c#, nlog

My program consists of a single EXE and 6 DLLs (and of course everyone references everyone), I currently have a crude static logging class (Logger) which is in its own DLL (Logger.dll) which I add as a reference to each of my projects and use ... but instead of re-inventing the wheel I was looking to replace this with nLog.

Problem is I can't seem to figure out how all my projects can share the same nLog config file (I want everything logging to the SAME file and I do not want to define a config file per project).

1. is there a way to have a single config file for all my projects?
2. is this safe to do? will nLog in each project accessing the same file not cause contention issues? does nLog already handle this correctly?

Or would it simply be best for me to wrap nLog in my static Logger.dll (odd to do but would work also) and keep doing things like I do today in my application?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NLog should handle what you want to .  The NLog.config file is applied at the application (EXE) level.  So, if you configure NLog in the NLog.config, the configuration will be read when the application starts.  All classes, whether in the EXE, or in one of your DLLs, when they retrieve a logger from NLog, will return a logger that has been configured according to the EXE-level NLog.config file.

Comment: I don't see how that works, I have an EXE which is referencing other DLLs, when I add NLOG to my EXE project I see it there but then when I go to my DLL projects (which has it own references) there is no link to NLOG and it has no clue what NLOG is until I add a new reference and NLOG config file to the new DLL project.

Comment: You need to add reference to NLOG to each project, including DLL projects, but you don't need to add NLog.config to the DLL projects, only the EXE project.

Comment: So in my DLLs what do I do (after adding a reference) to ensure I log to the same log file as my EXE?

Comment: You should not have to do anything special. It should just work. Well, you do have to get a Logger in each class where you want to log. There are plenty of examples of how to do that. You can go to my profile and look at my highest rated answer for more NLog tips.  Note, I will be without Internet access for a week or so. Good luck!

Comment: What is recommended if you want to share the NLog.config file across multiple applications in a single solution? For instance a web project and a WCF project.