# How to inject NLog as ILogger in multiple projects in net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, nlog, ilogger

Right now I'm creating a web service and I started using the NLog logger. I configured it and it works when using it in the web service project like this:

```
   [ApiController]
    public class SimpleController : BaseController<SimpleApi>
    {

        private readonly ILogger<SimpleController > _logger;


        public MarcatgeController(ILogger<SimpleController > logger, IServiceProvider provider) : base(provider)
        {
            _logger = logger ?? throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(logger));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SimpleMethod([FromBody]Request request)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("SimpleMethod");
            return ParseResponse(await CurrentApi.SimpleMethod(request));
        }
    }
```

But when using it on the project **API** (when it calls CurrentApi) nothing is logged:

```
    public class SimpleApi: BaseApi
    {
        private readonly ILogger<SimpleApi> _logger;

        public MarcatgeApi(ILogger<SimpleApi> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger ?? throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(logger));
        }

        public Task<Response<ResponseSimple> SimpleMethod(Request request)
        {
            _logger.LogDebug($"SimpleApi -> SimpleMethod()");

            return GetResponseSuccess<ResponseSimple>(resp);
        }
    }
```

The base controller class looks like this:

```
    public class BaseController<T> : Controller where T : BaseApi
    {
        protected T CurrentApi { get; private set; }

        public BaseController(IServiceProvider provider)
        {
            CurrentApi = (T)ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(provider, typeof(T));
        }
    }
```

If I use **NLog.Logger log = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();** on the **API** project It works, but I want to inject it to the constructor, how can I do it?

I tried to add the package NLog to all the projects where I want to use the logger like the solution of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13863120/11528557), but still didn't work.

EDIT: How I registered the NLog:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var logger = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("NLog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
            try
            {
                logger.Debug("init main");
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                //NLog: catch setup errors
                logger.Error(exception, "Stopped program because of exception");
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
              .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
              {
                  webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
              })
              .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
              .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
              {
                  logging.ClearProviders();
                  logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
              })
              .UseNLog();
        }
```

Api module registration:

```
 public class ApiModule
        : Autofac.Module
    {

        public ApiModule()
        {

        }

        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            try
            {
                builder.RegisterType<BaseApi>();
                builder.RegisterType<BaseAuthApi>();
                builder.RegisterType<MarcatgeApi>();

                var mapper = MappingProfile.InitializeAutoMapper().CreateMapper();

                // Registrem mapper
                builder.RegisterInstance<IMapper>(mapper);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: You just have to register Nlog in the DI framework. This seems like a good guide: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3#6-write-logs. Part 4 seems like the part you're missing.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put how I registered the NLog, but It's done exactly like the link, and still doesn't work

Comment: You manually seem to create these api's using `Activator.CreateInstance` this doesn't use DI or anything. Why don't you use `CurrentApi = provider.GetRequiredService<T>();`? (Remember to register your api's though!)

Comment: Also generally you want to avoid injecting the `IServiceProvider` just have the constructor ask for the things it wants.

Comment: I tried you solution registering my api's like this:
`builder.RegisterType<BaseApi>();`              
`builder.RegisterType<SimpleApi>();`
But still doesn't works

Comment: Can you add the code for that try? Also it would really help if you could give the line and error you're getting

Comment: @Knoop I've added how I registered the api's. The logger does not give an error, it simply does not log the messages.

Comment: Sounds more like your NLog config is wrong

Comment: Try changing from `LogDebug` to `LogWarning`. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Missing-trace%5Cdebug-logs-in-ASP.NET-Core-3%3F

Comment: @RolfKristensen When using LogWarning it works, I don't know why, I would check the link later to see if I can made the LogDebug work, thanks!

Comment: did you register NLog to your pipeline in program.cs file ?

Comment: Yes, I got it working with the solution provided by @RolfKristensen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it working with the answer of @RolfKristensen following his [link](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Missing-trace%5Cdebug-logs-in-ASP.NET-Core-3%3F).

I updated the logging section of my appsettings.json and appsettings.Development.json to the following:

```
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
```